# Finding position at the end of regex expression

Tags: regex, sas

I have a text variable in this format

```
1234  09.07 USD 50.00 SOME RELEVANT TEXT 
1234  09.07 USD 10000.00 SOME RELEVANT TEXT
```

I need the position of the first letter after the USD 50.00 part. Using regexp in SAS, I can find starting position of the pattern I am looking for, but how do I find the end position of the expression? The problem is that the amount might be 50.00 or 10000.00, hence the end posistion before the relevant text will differ, although the starting position is the same.

Using this expression;

```
    prxmatch('/\s\w{3}\s\d+\.\d+\s\w/' , myvar)
```

I can find the start of the USD part, but how do I get the position right before the SOME RELEVANT TEXT part? In this expression, I define "3 letters space anynumberofdigits.anynumberofdigits space letter".

I have started writing code where I am reversing the string, but I feels like I am missing an obvious and easy sollution here.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, "SOME RELEVANT TEXT" match "all non-digital symbols from the end":

```
/[^\d]+$/
```

**UPDATE:** 
If digits are allowed in "SOME RELEVANT TEXT", you can modify your initial regex this way:

```
/\s\w{3}\s\d+\.\d+\s(.+)/
```

Comment: The problem is, the SOME RELEVANT TEXT might contain a clean tekst such as SPOTIFY or WAYNES COFFE, but it might also be PVP 17.5 KM,SPAIN. Which your suggestion will not recognize, if I am not mistaken

Comment: Ok, I understand. Then you can modify your regex this way:     /\s\w{3}\s\d+\.\d+\s(.+)/

Comment: All characters seems to be allowed in the SOME RELEVANT TEXT part, further complicating things. I did find a cumbersome sollution though. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward to me.  I make your first bit a positive lookbehind for simplicity in this example (of course change this to a regular match if you prefer).

Please provide additional data if you want better answers if this does not match your data.

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 textvar $100.;
datalines;
1234  09.07 USD 50.00 SOME RELEVANT TEXT 
1234  09.07 USD 10000.00 SOME RELEVANT TEXT 
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  _rx = prxparse('/(?:\s\w{3}\s\d+\.\d+\s)(.*)$/');
  _rc = prxmatch(_rx,textvar);
  RelevantText = prxposn(_Rx,1,textvar);
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

This works, but is not quite elegant.

I basically reversed the string and searched for the reverse of the expression. This time formulating the entire first part of the string, not only "3 letters space anynumberofdigits.anynumberofdigits space letter"), as there were a few observations that increadibly enough, matched the first expression in the SOME RELEVANT TEXT part

```
tmp1=strip(reverse(myvar));
pos = prxmatch('/\s\d+\.\d+\s\w{3}\s\d{2}\.\d{2}\s\d{4}\*/' , tmp1) ;
relevanttext= reverse(substr(tmp1,1,pos));
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a particularly good solution.  Any regex you can use this way also has a non-reversed solution.

Comment: completely agree, not particularly good, but it works. Will try your suggestion instead.